# Partial not accessing local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am rendering a partial like so:

```
 <% @pages.each do |page| %>
     <%= render 'layouts/pagewithchildren', :locals => { :page => page } %>
 <% end %>
```

But when i try to access a variable in page i am getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `page'
```

I am accessing the variable like:

```
<%= page.title %>
```

So what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i'm not 100% sure but isn't it either

```
<%= render 'layouts/pagewithchildren', :page => page %>
```

or

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/pagewithchildren', :locals => { :page => page } %>
```

?

Comment: In Rails 5 the latter approach no longer works (with `locals`)

Answer (score 8):

You have to explicitly specify partial, otherwise, Rails will treat locals as a params hash, you can access locals[:page] but not page variable directly in your partial.

Change your code to:

```
<%= render partial:'layouts/pagewithchildren', locals: {page: page} %>
```